# Getting errors and missing dependencies when using create-react-app?

Tags: node.js, npm, create-react-app

I've recently started running into an error when creating new react apps using create-react-app. I've included the complete error log below:

```
$ npx create-react-app test-nginx-deploy
npx: installed 99 in 8.891s

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\jeff.barfield\Documents\B&R Fun\nginx Testing\test-nginx-deploy.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

C:\Users\jeff.barfield\Documents\B&R Fun\nginx Testing\test-nginx-deploy\react-scripts -> C:\Users\jeff.barfield\Documents\B&R Fun\nginx Testing\test-nginx-deploy\node_modules\react-scripts\bin\react-scripts.js

> core-js@2.6.11 postinstall C:\Users\jeff.barfield\Documents\B&R Fun\nginx Testing\test-nginx-deploy\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> core-js@3.6.4 postinstall C:\Users\jeff.barfield\Documents\B&R Fun\nginx Testing\test-nginx-deploy\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> core-js-pure@3.6.4 postinstall C:\Users\jeff.barfield\Documents\B&R Fun\nginx Testing\test-nginx-deploy\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\core-js-pure
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

+ react-dom@16.13.1
+ react@16.13.1
+ cra-template@1.0.3
+ react-scripts@3.4.1
added 1591 packages from 750 contributors in 82.103s
Missing dependencies in package.json
```

I have tried uninstalling create-react-app and reinstalling but had no luck.

**EDIT: Another item of note is that upon creating the app I end up with 2 files in the project root that I've never seen before when using create react app. react-scripts.cmd AND react-scripts which would both usually be in node_module/.bin

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5918?

Comment: Another item of note is that upon creating the app I end up with 2 files in the project root that I've never seen before when using create react app.

react-scripts.cmd AND react-scripts which would both usually be in node_module/.bin